# How does a "Rupoor" work?

Tags: legend-of-zelda-series

In *The Legend of Zelda* series, a Rupoor is an item that steals your money.

How does it work within the confines of the game world? Does the money just vanish? Does it get eaten? The question is asking how, using physics, the rupoor deducts rupees from Link. What kind of magical force makes the rupees disappear?

Comment: what your missing is that between reality and a video game there is a developer who often uses things that dont make sense. Its called "creative license", and asking what the developer was thinking is off topic for this sight. As such, we get told what they do, but not why.

Comment: This question isn't unclear at all. It clearly asks in the title, "How does a rupoor work?"

Comment: It calls a method which does something along the lines of `money -= moneyLost`

Comment: @Sandwich The reason why the question is put on hold as "unclear what you're asking" is because any attempt at answering the question would be speculation. You're asking how the rupoor works and why the rupoor exists (using an ostensibly in-universe explanation). Both of which cannot be answered by someone who didn't work on the game itself. You are asking why the game developers did something a certain way, which is asking for developer intent, something we cannot ascertain.

Comment: see my comment, google "creative license". The developers wanted a pickup that removes instead of adding rupees. very common element. They probably didnt think they would need to put in a realistic explanation to how it works, given the game world is full of magic and other fictional entities.

Comment: If it's a common element, name two other games that have a pickup that removes money from your wallet instead of adding it.

Comment: As your question is at the moment, the best answer you're going to get is "Magic!" We can't answer *how* it removes the rupees, just *what it does*

Comment: Looks clear to me. Voting to reopen. Seems to be an on-topic lore question too as per http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7696/should-lore-questions-as-an-entire-category-be-banned and http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7673/when-is-it-appropriate-to-close-a-lore-question-as-not-addressed-directly-throu.

Comment: The real question is, why does Link pick them up instead of just, like...stepping over them?

Comment: A Rupoor is an anti-money. When money and anti-money combine, they annihilate each other resulting in a burst of free market force radiation.

Comment: @CyberSkull One of the best answers I've seen so far, 10/10

Answer (score 2):

In *Four Swords*, the first game in which Rupoors appeared (though called Black Rupees), collecting one resulted in Rupees being ejected from your wallet. The players could pick the scattered money back up, but this is still a decent explanation: Rupoors repel Rupees like opposite-polarity magnets. This doesn't fully explain why lost money cannot be recollected in later games, but it's not a stretch to say it got flung somewhere that it can't be picked back up again.